# Jest test failing when using Array.prototype.includes with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs, angular-package-format

I started using Array.prototype.includes in this project:

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator

It is packaged using the Angular Package Format and the source is in this directory:

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator/tree/master/projects/validator

The project builds fine, however when the Jest tests are run this error occurs:

```
 FAIL  projects/validator/src/lib/decorators/IsDefined.spec.ts
  ● should create an error when using validate

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

      35 |   const mc: MetaClass = ValidationContainer.metaClasses.get(cn);
      36 |   if (mc) {
    > 37 |     const properties: string[] = mc.properties.filter(p => !exlude.includes(p))
```

So it seems as if Jest is not picking up the property typescript configuration, which does include:

```
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Log ```exlude``` and check if it exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the error. It's not that `includes` is not allowed.

It's that it cannot access the property `includes` on a value that is `undefined`, i.e. apparently you try to do `undefined.includes`, so that would mean that `exlude` must be `undefined`.

---

In your `IsDefined.spec.ts` you are calling `validate` like this:

```js
it(`should create an error when using validate`, ()=>{
  let IDI = new IsDefinedInvalid();
  let e = validate(IDI);
  expect(e.valid).toBeFalsy();
});
```

So, you are passing only 1 argument (`IDI`) to `validate`. However, in `validate.ts` you define the function like this:

```js
export function validate(target: any, exlude?: string[]): ObjectErrors {
  let oes: ObjectErrors = new ObjectErrors();
  const cn: string = target.constructor.name;
  const mc: MetaClass = ValidationContainer.metaClasses.get(cn);
  if (mc) {
    const properties: string[] = mc.properties.filter(p => !exlude.includes(p))
    properties.forEach(p => {
      if (!validateProperty(target, p, oes)) {
        oes.valid = false;
      }
    });
  }
  return oes;
}
```

As you can see, `validate` takes *two* arguments - `target` and `exlude`. (By the way, that is misspelled and should be `exclude` with a `c`.) Yes, `exlude` is marked as optional with `?`, so it's contractually OK that you omit it, however inside the `validate` function you then use `exlude` (in the line that crashed) without first checking whether it is `undefined`, so you end up calling `undefined.includes(p)`!

To be honest, I'm not sure why the TypeScript compiler isn't complaining at this point. (Maybe a commenter has an idea why...)

Anyway, the solution is to set a default value of `[]` in the function definition in `validate.ts`:

```js
export function validate(target: any, exlude: string[] = []): ObjectErrors {
```

(Of course it would also work to pass the second argument as empty array when calling the function (`validate(IDI, [])`), but then the bug in `validate` will still exist.)